# C++ templates: Accessing template variables

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ world.

I am trying to implement code using templates.

```
template<class PageType>
class Book
{
 //implementation
public:
  PageType* FreeQ; //holds the pointers to pages which are yet to be written
  PageType* BusyQ; //holds the pointers to pages which are being written 
  PageType* DoneQ; //holds the pointers to pages which were written
  getPagetoWrite(); //Get from FreeQ and put in BusyQ 
  setPageAsFree();  //Erase data and put in FreeQ
}

//example for PageType implementation
class PlasticType
{
  mutex; // must
  status; // must
  *prev; // must
  *next; // must
  Write( );
  Read();  
}
```

I want to know whether there is any way to inform the compiler that implementation of `PageType` **must** contain specific variables which will be used in class `Book` implementation (in `getPagetoWrite` and `setPageAsFree`)   without creating the instance of the type `PageType`.

Hope i made myself clear.

Comment: Well, if your template code mentions those variables and they don't exist then there will be a compilation error.

Comment: The part of C++ which allows you to declare what `PageType` must contain is called "concepts," and it's scheduled to be added in the 2017 timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that it is possible to enforce that `PageType`  contain specific variables, this is done simple at compile time during template instantiation - and you really dont need anything else. You can use C++11 `std::is_base_of` to enforce with `static_assert` that your `PageType` implements some base class to which you could put getPagetoWrite  and setPageAsFree, but still you will have to instantiate your templates - which is OK.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base {
};

class X : public Base {
};

class Z {
};

template <typename T> 
class Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base,T>::value,"must be derived from Base");
public:
    Foo() {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo<Z> foo_z_type; // gives compile error: static assertion failed: must be derived from Base
    Foo<X> foo_z_type; // OK
    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf91079681af3b0e

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can just use the variables' or functions' names that should be there in your code. Like this:

```
void getPagetoWrite()
{    
...
//PageType should have a member called pagenum for which operator++ makes sense
BusyQ->pagenum++;
...
}
```

If then you instantiate your Book template with some class which doesn't have a `pagenum` member, you will get a compile time error.